# Lottery: Missing one ball query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to solve a problem with lottery numbers. There's a table *card*, which has numbers of a lottery:

Table: card

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| ID | b1 | b2 | b3 | b4 | b5 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 1  | 10 | 12 | 14 | 15 | 17 |
| 2  | 01 | 13 | 30 | 44 | 50 |
| 3  | 15 | 14 | 28 | 46 | 60 |
| 4  | 09 | 10 | 32 | 47 | 59 |
| 5  | 14 | 10 | 25 | 47 | 58 |
```

The game is with balls. First we sort one ball (12), after other (15), like this list:

```
12, 15, 17, 30, 32, 40, 2, 14
```

I need to select the first row, which will be the winner if the next ball is 10.

I don't know how to say in English, but I need the state of card that needs one number to be the winner.

Today, my sql is like this (trying all possibilities):

```
SELECT id FROM card WHERE b1 IN (12, 15, 17, 30, 32, 40, 2, 14) AND 
                          b2 IN (12, 15, 17, 30, 32, 40, 2, 14) ... OR 
                          b2 IN (12, 15, 17, 30, 32, 40, 2, 14) AND b3...
```

Can anybody help? Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to find the rows that match all the balls or just the first one? If you have a ball that said "15" would you want it to return "row 3" or would you need to match 15, 14, 28, 46, 60?

Comment: @TerryCarmen I need to select all rows that missing 1 number to be the winner and i need the id col only.

Comment: So if the user gets 14, 28, 46, 60, you want it to say "3"?

Comment: Yeah, that's righ

Comment: 3 or more rows that can be missing one number

Comment: What does it mean for row to be a winner?

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Actually, It's a card that's missing a ball to win.

Comment: Explain what card is. You want to select `id`, `card`, as you say is thw **table** containing all `id`s...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rare case where a key-value structure makes solving the problem easier. You don't really care which column the value's in, just if the id has the value associated with it. I don't think MySQL has an unpivot function, but you can do this fairly easily manually:

```
SELECT   id
FROM     (SELECT id, 1 AS rw, b1 AS VALUE FROM card
          UNION ALL
          SELECT id, 2 AS rw, b2 AS VALUE FROM card
          UNION ALL
          SELECT id, 3 AS rw, b3 AS VALUE FROM card
          UNION ALL
          SELECT id, 4 AS rw, b4 AS VALUE FROM card
          UNION ALL
          SELECT id, 5 AS rw, b5 AS VALUE FROM card) v
WHERE    VALUE IN (12,
                   15,
                   17,
                   30,
                   32,
                   40,
                   2,
                   14)
GROUP BY id
HAVING   COUNT (*) = 4
```

(This query was tested on Oracle, rather than MySQL, so the syntax may not be precisely correct.)

Comment: Wow, that's a very ingenious solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The best way is you create a table of sorting balls, and after this you query the sorted in that like:

```
SELECT id FROM card WHERE b1 IN (SELECT ball FROM balls)
AND b2 IN (SELECT ball FROM balls)
AND b3 IN (SELECT ball FROM balls)
AND b4 IN (SELECT ball FROM balls)
AND b5 IN (SELECT ball FROM balls)
```

After each sort you save the ball number in balls table:

```
INSERT INTO balls(ball) VALUES (10);
```

Comment: In this example, i would be able to get only the **winner**. I need cards that are missing 1 ball to win.

Comment: Ok, so you'll need to put one of this condition in OR clause, like this:
SELECT id 
FROM card WHERE 
(
  (
    b1 IN (SELECT ball FROM balls)
    AND b2 IN (SELECT ball FROM balls)
    AND b3 IN (SELECT ball FROM balls)
    AND b4 IN (SELECT ball FROM balls)
  ) OR AND b5 IN (SELECT ball FROM balls)
)
OR
... and alter each field 'B(number)' in outside the AND in OR clause.

Comment: With this method, you might be able to pull off `SELECT id FROM card JOIN balls ON ball IN (b1,b2,b3,b4,b5) GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*) = 4`...

Answer (score 1):

I would record your picks differently in a vertical manner:

Also this is a SQL server answer so formatting might be slightly off.

```
--Correct balls    
declare @b1 int =2
    ,@b2 int = 10
    ,@b3 int = 15
    ,@b4 int = 21
    ,@b5 int = 45



declare @t as table (ID int, pick int)

insert into @t
values
 (1,10),(1,12),(1,14),(1,15),(1,17)
,(2,1),(2,13),(2,30),(2,44),(2,50)

--This gives you the number right per ID
--I commented out the answer for 4 or more to get you results
select ID, sum(case when pick in (@b1,@b2,@b3,@b4,@b5) then 1 else 0 end)
from @t
group by id
--having sum(case when pick in (@b1,@b2,@b3,@b4,@b5) then 1 else 0 end) >=4
```

This is a 2 for 1 answer...

To get your data right use this as your picks table. When I say right, I mean normalized, which allows this game to let you pick unlimited amount of balls without changing the table structure.

```
Select ID
,
A.pick
From picks
Cross apply (values (b1),(b2),(b3),(b4),(b5)) a(pick)
```

Sorry for format. Doing this from phone

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the PIVOT function. then all the values of B1 would be in the same row. b2,b3,b4,b5...